# Я пытаюсь создать функцию, которая рисует заданное изображение .bmp в заданном окне

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы, bmp

Я понял, что скорее всего проблема либо на стадии создания массива Pixels, то есть я как-то неправильно обращаюсь к элементам динамического массива, либо на стадии передачи массива в функцию CreateBitmap. Ей нужен указатель void*, возможно дело в этом. Как передать значение правильно? (сейчас функция рисует пару строчек пикселей случайного цвета).

Функции `set_pixel, get_pixel bitmap_image()` это библиотека, которая находится тут: https://gist.github.com/kelbon/eedb4c093abf5c1d00a7cd332ae250f1

```
void DrawingBitmap(HDC kuda, unsigned int whereX, unsigned int whereY, const std::string &NameFile, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
{
    bitmap_image input(width, height); 
    input = bitmap_image(NameFile);
    rgb_t perenos;
    unsigned int i, j;

    //выделение памяти под массив указателей на строки
    COLORREF** Pixels = new COLORREF * [height];

    // выделение памяти под пиксели в строках
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        Pixels[i] = new COLORREF[width];
    }

    //работа с массивом данных
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            perenos = input.get_pixel(j, i);
            Pixels[i][j] = RGB(perenos.red, perenos.green, perenos.blue);
        }
    }

    //создал по взятому по номеру окну участок памяти, совместимый с устройством на который указывает hdcConsole
    HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(kuda);

    HBITMAP memBM = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 32, Pixels);
    (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, memBM);

    // Для контекста памяти устанавливаем тот же режим отображения, что используется в контексте отображения
    SetMapMode(memDC, GetMapMode(kuda));

    //рисую изображение
    BitBlt(kuda, whereX, whereY, width, height, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // Восстанавливаем контекст памяти
    SelectObject(memDC, memBM);

    // Удаляем контекст памяти
    DeleteDC(memDC);

    // освобождение памяти в строках
    for (i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        delete[] Pixels[i];
    }

    //освобождение памяти от массива указателей на строки
    delete[] Pixels;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateBitmap нужно передавать не массив строк, а сразу массив пикселей, размером width*height. По строкам надо только обеспечить выравнивание (Each scan line in the rectangle must be word aligned (scan lines that are not word aligned must be padded with zeros)). Скорее всего, выравнивание и так есть, можно подстраховаться:

```
assert( sizeof(COLORREF)*width % sizeof(WORD) == 0 );
```

Comment: А как тогда реализовать это? Ведь любой двумерный массив это массив строк.  Я уже делал программу без функции, где делал размер фиксированного размера и у меня получалось

Comment: но функция CreateBitmap не принимает одномерные массивы насколько я понимаю

Comment: Сюрприз - нет, в терминах С, двумерный массив это не массив строк. В обоих случаях к элементу можно обращаться arr[i][j], но в первом случае у вас непрерывный шмат памяти, по которому можно ходить инкрементом указателя от arr[0][0] до arr[n-1][m-1], во втором - массив указателей плюс m массивов элементов. Попробуйте переделать программу начиная с "COLORREF* Pixels = new COLORREF [height*width];"

Comment: Я конечно могу попробовать создать одномерный массив и потом ходить по нему в цикле как *(Pixels[height*i+width]), но что-то мне подсказывает, что функция CreateBitmap не сможет понять что я ей дал

Comment: А можно кстати создать и так: new COLORREF [height][width], тогда Pixels будет двумерным массивом. (Но это не массив строк!)

Comment: ну вообще то это так не работает, пишет нельзя использовать width как константу. Естественно я уже пытался так делать

Comment: Вау, в общем я написал ((COLORREF*)Pixels1)[i * width + j] = RGB(perenos.red, perenos.green, perenos.blue); и это сработало, оказывается функция обучена работать с таким массивом. Но это мягко говоря неочевидно. Я даже сам об этом думал(реализацию увидел у Страуструпа в книге), но мне показалось глупым давать функции одномерный массив.....МДААААААААААА

Comment: А, да наврал слегка. Компилятору там нужна константа, чтобы превращать Pixels[i][j] в Pixels[i * width + j].